# How can I remove the argslist files from the buffer list?

Tags: buffers

When using the args list, Vim adds those arglist files to the buffer list.
Once I'm finished with the argslist, I then have many unwanted argslist files in the bufferlist.
They don't have a contiguous number sequence, so I cant just say, `:11,24 bd`.
Is it possible to remove these files from the bufferlist?, possibly using the same pattern I used to create the arglist? e.g.

```
:bd tests/unit/**/*.js
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:argdo`:

```
:argdo bd
```

`:argdo {cmd}` will run command, `{cmd}`, on every item in the argslist. In this case you use `:bdelete` as the command to unload the buffer and delete it from the buffer list.

For more help see: `:h :argdo`

Comment: thanks for this. I think you have a typo - argodo? This works for the question -  as I phrased it so I guess I should accept but I dont know if it would help the community because I just realised deleting the entire arglist would be too indiscriminate. any files you were actually editing (as opposed to arglist operations)  would also be closed by this

Comment: In general I find "cleaning up" the buffer list for the sake of tidiness to be a bit silly. It doesn't really matter how many buffers you have open (as long as they are small). Using `:b` with a partial name or a fuzzy finder to switch between buffers often removes the need to view the buffer list via `:ls`. I often have 50+ buffers open at a time without concern. Of course, your workflow may have different needs.

Comment: wow, that makes sense. It would be liberating to stop maintaining the bufferlist! the main reason I have been doing it is because when I open a buffer by `:ls` , `:b #` I can control how the placement of  windows AND the files in them. my fuzzy finder  - ctrlp - and project explorer - nerdtree - dont use the buffer workflow. So i needed the bufferlist because it does. but they do provide the ability e.g. `ctrlp`, `ctrl-o`, `r` does open a buffer in the current window. and nerdtree does have a buffer explorer

Comment: Here is a piece of advice: don't mix a plugin-based workflow with a defaults-based workflow. Plugins tend to operate within the boundaries of their design and generally don't play very well with default commands.